# choosing the nth element in a matlab cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell array VsCell with dimension 1000x1 (or more). Each item in VsCell is a 501x567 matrix. I want to extract elements occupying a position in all the matrices contained in the cell. Basically something like:

VsCell{:}(1,1) - for all the first elements of the arrays in the cell
VsCell{:}(2,1) - for all the first row 2 elements of the arrays in the cell.

Subsequently, I intend to take the mean or median of these selection and fill a single [501x567] matrix array, which would represent the mean/median/etc of the VsCell arrays e.g. mean(VsCell{:}(1,1)).

I tried  VsCell{:}(1,1) - but it returns "Bad cell reference operation."

Also, is there a way to achieve this with little or no for loops/cellfun? 
I couldn't really achieve this using examples found online.

Thank you very much for your time, I am glad to clarify further if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do can be done with cells, without loops or `cellfun`, that is. Cells are heterogeneous data structures, there's no guarantee that each element will have a compatible shape. Heck, element number 3 in your cell could even be another cell, or a string, or a custom class instance! I'm just saying that I don't find it surprising that cells can't be indexed into in the way you're trying to.

However, you *can* con`cat`enate your cell into a higher-dimensional array, and work with that:

```
VsMat = cat(3,VsCell{:}); % cell as comma separated list
MatMeans = mean(VsMat,3); % mean along dimension 3, where they are concatenated
MatMedians = median(VsMat,3);
MatSums = sum(VsMat,3);
```

Working with arrays should be faster anyway, so except for the single trade-off of calling `cat` (which is slow), you're probably better off using homogeneous arrays anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andras! You are right, I chose to work with arrays for speed. cat is not too too bad for the job, it does a better job than using a nested for-loop, considering my dataset could grow really big.

Comment: The cat method works fine up to a size limit of array, after which I get out of memory error. Do you perhaps have any suggestion. I would not mind even the cellfun or for loop implementation at this point. Thanks

Comment: @QP1 that's interesting, I would think that the array you get after `cat()` occupies less space than the cell itself. Two possible explanations are that (1) your data is so large that only one copy fits into memory at the same time, so the original cell+new array is too much, or (2) `cat` has memory overhead. In the second case you can pre-allocate with `VsMat=zeros([size(VsCell{1},length(VsCell)]);` then set `VsMat(:,:,k)` in a loop over `k` instead of using `cat`. In the first case I'm not sure there's an easy way out, so try the second first;)