# MATLAB indexing all the cells in a cell array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a cell array where each cell contains a matrix (different sizes). I would like, e.g., to take all the second columns of the matrices providing a command like:

```
aux = cArray{:}(:,2)
```

The result I'd like to obtain is a cell array where each cell contains the second column of the original matrix, but the command doesn't work (and I can even see why, since the output of cArray{:} is not a matrix ... )
Is there a compact command to get what I want instead of a cycle filling up the cell array ?

Comment: @Luis's answer shows how it's done, but if your cell elements are all the same size, you should consider switching to multidimensional arrays. Yesterday [a very similar question came up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37557025/5067311) (blatant self-promotion), you can find there how *that* is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is that indexing a cell array with `{:}` produces a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), which is not indexable anymore. You can view it as the "unwrapped" contents of the cell array separated by commas.

You can achieve what you want with [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
result = cellfun(@(x) x(:,2), cArray, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

This applies the anonymous function `@(x) x(:,2)` to each cell's contents, and packs the results in a cell array.